# Periodically calling an health check API in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new in angular and trying to build a health check connection to check the availability of my backend im background. This check will run periodically each 5s to check if an 200 OK status is received:

Here is my service:

```
healthCheck() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.healthCheckAPI, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        map((resp: any) => {
          if(resp.status !== 200){
            throw resp;
          }
          return resp.status;
        }),
        repeatWhen(() => interval(5000)),
        retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(5000)))
      );
  }
```

And here is inside of my component:

```
this.apiService.healthCheck().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        //perform some stuff when 200 is returned
      },
      (error) => {
        //perform some stuff when error is returned
      }
    );
```

In the `subscribe()` method in my component, I successfully got the status 200 when the healthCheck is successful, but why I never get the error part in my subscribe method, even when the backend is unavailable? I thought in that case, the service will call the `retryWhen()` in the background and return the error to the component so that I can make some operation there, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The operators `retryWhen` and `retry` will **not** emit the `error` notification. It'll trigger the observable again and wait for the next notification.

If you wish to do something on an error notification in the component and still use the `retryWhen` operator, you could move the subscriptions callbacks to a `tap` operator before the subscription.

Service

```js
healthCheck() {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.healthCheckAPI, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
    map((resp: any) => {
      if(resp.status !== 200){
        throw resp;
      }
      return resp.status;
    }),
    repeatWhen(() => interval(5000))
  );
}
```

Component

```js
this.apiService.healthCheck().pipe(
  tap(
    (data) => {
      // perform some stuff when 200 is returned
    },
    (error) => {
      // perform some stuff when error is returned
    }
  ),
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(5000)))
).subscribe();
```

However note there are multiple issues with this approach

- People usually frown upon relying on `tap` operator.
- The `retryWhen` is in the component level now. So each subscription should pipe it in individuall to retry the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the check every 5 seconds with `interval()`.

It could be like :

```
interval(5000)
  .pipe(switchMap(this.apiService.healthCheck()))
  .subscribe((success) => {console.log('up')}, error => console.err('down'))
```